# How to save an image inlined into an email using the stock Email app?

Tags: images, stock-email-app

I received an email containing an inline photo (not as attachment, but inside the message body) and I would like to save this image as a file, so that I can for instance open it in my gallery.

I'm using the stock Android Email app (com.android.email, version 4.4.4). I see no menu indicating how to do it, and a long touch on the image opens no menu either.

If there's no way to do it from inside the application, I'd accept indications on how to do it from e.g. a terminal if possible (my phone is rooted, but I don't know if email inline images are separately saved as files).

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a way to save it in a traditonal manner, but it's a good last resort. You could take a screenshot (usually Power+Volume Down) and then crop it in the Photos app (in the Google version there is a pencil icon at the bottom of the picture).

Comment: Also, restarting your phone or force-stopping the email app could help.